# Shiny plot not showing

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

My code looks like this:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    DataRead <- reactive(input$PlotType)
    CR <- reactive(as.character(input$ContributionRate))
    PlotData <- reactive(get(paste(CR(),DataRead(),sep="")))
    output$gPlot <- renderGvis({gvisLineChart(PlotData(),
        options=...)
    })
})
```

I'm assuming the `get()` function isn't passing the data.frame through to `PlotData()`, which makes the HTML render blank.

My `ui.R` is using `htmlOutput()`.

Anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: Try something with return() or print(). If you can store a ggvisplot in an object you can use that object or otherwise put it directly around yhe gvis function

Comment: It didn't help. It's either not rendering properly or there is nothing to render, since I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: I ran it in a browser and it's working fine now, except that one of my plots with 6 lines is only rendering a few of them, and as I move the slider, more disappear.

However, if I mouse over the line, the data points are still there. The line just isn't being colored.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML only renders in a browser window. That was my issue.

However, now there is a problem where not all of the lines will show. The points still display data when moused-over but the line itself is invisible.